# how to fetch images api in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am not getting images, but data are fetching perfect as expected.
*output of result*: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbXVc.png

**i am new to reactjs. i tried fetch method to hook the browserable-api, here below is my code. it would be great if anybody could help me out. advance thank you.**

./src/hook.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import Contacts from './contacts.js';


export default class App  extends Component{

    state = {
        contacts: []
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          this.setState({ contacts: data })
        })
        .catch(console.log)
      }

    render(){
    return(

        <Contacts contacts={this.state.contacts} />
    )
 }
}
```

./src/contacts.js

```
 import React from 'react'

    const Contacts = ({ contacts }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <center><h1>Contact List</h1></center>
          {contacts.map((contact) => (
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">{contact.title}</h5>
                <img src="{contact.url}" />
                <p class="card-text">{contact.url}</p>
                <p class="card-text">{contact.id}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      )
    };

    export default Contacts
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You placed quotes around the image's src prop value and bracket syntax, which makes the image source literally `"{contact.url}"` and isn't valid.

```
<img src="{contact.url}" />
```

Should be the value `contact.url` resolves to

```
<img src={contact.url} />
```

[image: Edit nervous-leftpad-0sjhf]

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="{contact.url}" />
```

You've put quotes around your src, so it's using literally "{contact.url}" as a string.

The curly braces are how it knows to compute your code as JavaScript.